# Fail to ping github.com with proxy

Tags: github, ping

I set a proxy for my git but I can not ping github.com by using it in my Git Bash. (error: time out)

In the meantime, I can approach github.com by chrome which is also using the same proxy.

Comment: Pinging through a proxy doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but if that's really what you want to do, you could look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147558/proxy-for-command-line-utilities-in-win-xp . It would help if you explain why you want to ping github.com ... what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`ping` don't (and can't) use a proxy.

Comment: thanks for comments! Could you help me or give me any advice to solve my problem about failing to ping github.com please?